# Eclipse Mars throwing Noclassdeffounderror when adding server runtime configuration

Tags: eclipse, cloud, sap, platform, eclipse-mars

I am using Eclipse Mars for SAP cloud application development. I added the SAP plug ins successfully. Now when I am adding a Java Web as a server runtime using the Java Web Sdk, it is throwing an error "server error Java /sql /time". When I see the log file it says Noclassdeffounderror for Java. Sql. Time. Could anyone help.

Regards, 
Nayeem

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Mars is tremendously outdated. You [should use Oxygen](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/) for SAP Cloud development and fulfill all necessary prerequisites for it.

[image]